# Как инициализировать колекцию записей с типом данных RECORD?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Вот простой пример двумерного массива в PL/SQL, который отлично работает:

```sql
declare
    type a is table of number;
    type b is table of a;

    arr b := b(a(1, 2), a(3, 4));
begin
    for i in arr.first .. arr.last loop
        for j in arr(i).first .. arr(i).last loop
            dbms_output.put_line(arr(i) (j));
        end loop;
    end loop;
end;
```

Что мне нужно, создать нечто подобное таблицы элементов с типом данных `RECORDS`.
Вот так:

```sql
type a is record(a1 number, a2 number);
type b is table of a;
```

Как я могу инициализировать этот тип данных, или его можно заполнить только в
запросе с `bulk collect`?

Синтаксис как в примере выше не работает:

```sql
arr b := b(a(1, 2), a(3, 4));
```

> PLS-00222: no function with name 'A' exists in this scope

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/3707140/6571020

Comment: Чисто из любопытства - почему не подошёл “bulk collect”?

Comment: Да, мне тоже не совсем понятно. Наверное, укоренившийся "страх" от переключения контекста.

Answer (score 2):

Не существует синтаксиса конструктора для типа данных `RECORD`. Их нужно заполнять так:

```sql
declare
    type a is record(a1 number, a2 number);
    type b is table of a;
    arr b := b();
begin
    arr.extend(2);
    arr(1).a1 := 1;
    arr(1).a2 := 2;
    arr(2).a1 := 3;
    arr(2).a2 := 4;
end;
```

<sub>Источник: [@TonyAndrews](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3707583/6571020)</sub>

---

Можно самому определить функцию конструктор для таких типов данных:

```sql
declare  
    type a is record(a1 number, a2 number);
    type b is table of a;
    arr b;
    function a_(a1 number, a2 number) return a is
        r a;
    begin
        r.a1 := a1;
        r.a2 := a2;
        return(r);
    end;
begin
    arr := b(a_(1, 2), a_(3, 4));
    for i in arr.first .. arr.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line(arr(i).a1||','||arr(i).a2);
    end loop;
end;
```

<sub>Источник: [@Shallow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29211228/6571020)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с 18c квалифицированные выражения [*Qualified Expressions*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/release-changes.html#GUID-0DAD7856-4AB9-4DBF-AD48-DD24B454E74D) дают дополнительную возможность задать значения для комплексных типов данных, что упрощает их инициализацию и  делает код понятней.

Для всех PL/SQL типов данных, включая `RECORD` и ассоциативные коллекции с символьным ключом (index-by-array), теперь доступен синтаксис конструктора:

```sql
declare 
    type rowType is record (id number, name varchar (32));
    type arrType is table of rowType index by varchar2 (16);
    arr arrType := arrType ('key1'=>rowType (1, 2), 'key2'=>rowType (3, 4)); 
begin null; end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```